# need to convert a bytearray to an image without using imageIO or fileoutputstream

Tags: java, sockets, applet

I have to send an image over a socket . so I, the client convert the image to a bytearray and send it as such.

The server.. being the applet recieves the byte array. - fine till here.

I must use Java 1.3 so NO ImageIO or Image classes.

and then since we have an applet - no fileoutputstream

Any other ways??

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/java/awt/image/MemoryImageSource.html#MemoryImageSource(int,%20int,%20java.awt.image.ColorModel,%20byte[],%20int,%20int) isn't an option?

Answer (score 3):

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(byte[] imagedata,
                  int imageoffset,
                  int imagelength)
```

It returns Image and it's available @since     JDK1.1 according to javadoc